# VB.NET classes that manipulate with Bluetooth

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth

Which .NET classes manipulates with Bluetooth device event, for example multimedia programs pause/play video whene bluetooth headset button pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No classes in .NET Framework allows you to do this. You must use 3rd party library, for example 32feet.NET (https://github.com/inthehand/32feet).